# React-Native Expo application on Github to the public

Tags: react-native, github, heroku, expo, ngrok

I have a Github repository for a react native app running with the expo. I want to use Heroku to make that react app public. Is that possible? If yes, then how can I do it? If no, then how to make a local react native expo app public?

Note: I used NGROK to make it public but I need to change the code every 2 hours because the generated NGROK URL expires every 2 hours.

Edit: There is an option in Heroku to connect your Github Repository and deploy the app. But how do I do that given that I use NGROK URLs every time for a request?

Comment: are you asking for the github repository to go public or upload the react app to server/site?

Comment: @xAtifx I have my React Native application code in a Github repo. I want that react native app to go public using Heroku.

Comment: @xAtifx hope the edit makes my doubt a bit more clear?